# How to partition web application in Docker

Tags: java, docker

I just need to verify I'm not over complicating things. I prefer the idea of data-only containers over volumes on host system.

I want to divide usual java webapp as follows

- server image(server env common at my place)
- db image
- application deployables(data-only)
- configuration(data-only)
- db data(data-only)
- log data volume(somewhere on host system)

I see some issues

- how can I maintain multiple configuration images i.e. dev, test, QA?(as Docker Hub do not support branches)
- I hope I can use "docker export" to move the db data around, in case of debbuging, right?
- is it even possible to have database files on external location(data-only container) for all databases?
- how to put it together, are there other possibilities than Docker Compose as it is said "We don’t recommend that you use it in production yet."?

Answer (score 1):

1. It supports :) You can decide between tags/branches when you setup your automated build.
2. docker export exports the filesystem regardless it related to the database or not. Better to use the database engine's own export tool like mysqldump for mysql. You can run it independently as a container with database linking or use process injection with docker exec to export
3. you need to mount the external location (if you want to host it on different server) then use volumes, but don't run more than one engine against the same database files. If you want to run multiple databases, just create separate folder/volume to them
4. You can setup a CoreOS cluster with systemd/etcd and you can use Fleet to write Unit files to describe the structure of your apps(services). Fleet has more options than the docker compose and designed for distributed/clustered environment. Just go to the CoreOS page and check the  example. Unfortunately docker compose is a quite limited tool at the moment

Comment: ad 1. it is more about being able to select from separate branches on docker hub, i.e. test/someimage/devbranch or test/someimage/prodbranch. So you can say to testers download dev branch for you env. Other option is to have multiple images in docker hub test/someimage-test and test/someimage-prod. Will check the Fleet tool.

Comment: ad 3. if I will have data-container with some DB -files  containing DB in same state can I copy(send) it to someone and will he be able with his DB server image to read those files? Is there no encryption or hashing in place? Usually we use DB dump instead